# Работа метода srt.isupper(), str.islower() python

Tags: python, методы

Появилась нужда в изменении регистра алфавита в случае, если хоть одна буква вводимой строки - Верхнего регистра.

```
if str_list_of_letters.isupper():
   alphabet = list(''.join(alphabet).upper())
```

Судя по документации метод str.isupper() возвращает True, если в строке есть хотя бы 1 символ в верхнем регистре.

> A string is uppercase if all cased characters in the string are
>   uppercase and    there is at least one cased character in the string.

Если я ошибаюсь - поправьте. 
Вопрос - есть ли возможность проверить есть ли хоть одна буква в верхнем регистре, без проверки каждого символа в цикле? Тот же вопрос про нижний.

Comment: Без цикла вообще никак не обойтись, просто либо его пишешь ты, либо другой разработчик какой нибудь библиотеки

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли описание. «A cased character is any character that can be expressed as upper or lower case.»

Comment: "...if **all** cased characters..."

Comment: Без цикла никак не обойтись. Когда Вы вызываете `str.isupper()`, то под капотом этой функции всё равно где-то есть цикл, который пробегает по каждой букве. Для читаемости можно написать `any(letter.isupper() for letter in str_list_of_letters)`.

Comment: Приведенная фраза переводится иначе: `str.isupper()` вернет `True` если **все** символы, регистр которых может быть изменен, находятся в верхнем регистре, и при этом есть хотя бы один такой символ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так, например, узнать без цикла есть ли хоть один символ, чей регистр отличается от остальных, но в этом случае нельзя узнать какой именно это символ, и верхнего регистра он или нижнего

```
a = 'строКа для проверки'

print(a == a.lower())  # False
```

Comment: Вообще вы ответили на вопрос, но я хотел бы узнать ещё варианты решения. Через несколько часов отмечу как верный, если больше никто не ответит.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно адекватное поведение - True если все символы одного заданного регистра

```
>>> 'строка'.isupper()
False
>>> 'строка'.islower()
True
>>> 'стрОка'.isupper()
False
>>> 'стрОка'.islower()
False
```

> Вопрос - есть ли возможность проверить есть ли хоть одна буква в
>   верхнем регистре, без проверки каждого символа в цикле?

```
'стрОка'.islower() == False
```